Habitable world with abnormally low Argon
I want to create a habitable earth-like world (water oceans etc) that is very scarce in Argon (only 4.37ppm of the atmosphere). Two of the easiest explanations for this are:

The world is very young, so the Potassium-40 has not been able to emit enough Argon-40 yet.
The world was terraformed by a technologically advanced species.

Unfortunately, in my story, neither of these options fit the plot. Are there any other ways I can have such an unusually low Argon content in the world’s atmosphere?
Note: although the world having less Potassium-40 would seem to be a good explanation, having such low Potassium-40 that Argon is only a minuscule trace gas seems to be problematic in terms of having a realistic terrestrial internal composition.
Stats of the world:
Mass: 1/3rd Earth’s
Radius: 0.7 Earth’s
Atmospheric pressure at surface: 4.756atm (Mostly Oxygen and Nitrogen. Yes this pressure seems high for a low-mass world, don’t worry. I have escape velocity and everything figured out, it will be stable and can be sustained through outgassing as well.)
World has a magnetic field and drip-and-plume tectonics.

Why do you need such a low concentration of Argon?  K-40 is only one source of Ar, and is the least important.

Is it actually of importance somehow to the plot that argon specifically is scarce? This seems rather like you're going at things the wrong way around. Details like this should be consequences of other aspects of the setting, not something that you arbitrarily add in and then contrive some convoluted justification for. Whatever that justification ends up being, it's likely to have plausibility issues that break suspension of disbelief or cause outright plot holes.

AS an addition to @ChristopherJamesHuff decent comment about plausibility. you seem to be going for high scientific accuracy, which is great! but when complex points like this crop up, leading to needing plausible reasons, it tends to split the audience in 2... half people who understand the science enough and your reasoning needs to be thorough and accurate or they'll get annoyed. and the second set who don't know enough science who are now annoyed they've had to read a scientific paper about argon... its doable but its a fine line so be careful

What are the consequences you fear to face if that Argon level is so low? I mean, I can't come up with a reason why we wouldn't be able to survive without Argon in the atmosphere...

@Antares Argon-40 is derived from the decay of Potassium-40, which is common in all terrestrial planets that have any substantial radiogenic heating. Without this radiogenic heating, the planet’s processes such as the carbon cycle, volcanic outgassing and other important geological processes will be hindered or halted all together.

@BladeWraith if I have a sufficiently consistent and accurate understanding of why my planet has such low Argon, it will allow me to create a world that at the very least makes sense to the audience. “The supply of Argon in the atmosphere of the world is very low because of x”

@Casualwoldbuilder: Then your problem is not having low Argon, but having too little radiogenic heating on the planet instead, isn't it?

But why do you want the planet to have low argon, if you aren't starting out with a reason why this would be so? If all you can come up if is reasons it wouldn't be so, maybe it shouldn't be.

It's not uncommon for worldbuilders to be reticent to share story details... but we're trying to consider alternative solutions to your problem and we can only do that if we know why your story is dependent on low argon. Argon-40 is 99.6% of all natural argon, making it the only one you can lower to solve your problem, and it only comes from Potassium-40 decay, which means you're screwed because you need potassium-40 to have a habitable planet. Sure you don't want to help us help you?

On a side note, the idea came to mind to bind the Argon. It's not gone, it's unavailable. Similar consequence - if you can rationalize it. (I'm nowhere near the chemist needed to make that happen.) Personally, I'm leaning toward solar conditions that cause ArH+ in the upper atmosphere. However, if you're married to Argon, there's going to come a point where you have to fake it because a brief rundown of the science suggests it's a consequence of key processes that can't be ignored unless, like so many authors before you, you do just ignore it and move forward.

Argon in the Earth's atmosphere is continuously being generated by potassium-40 decay, and being lost to space in the upper atmosphere. You want something that reduces the equilibrium concentration of argon to 0.0005 of the Earth's equilibrium concentration. That means scrubbing the atmosphere very thoroughly, and sticking the argon where it cannot come back. Losing it to space is probably the only solution.

Secondary atmosphere, the planet isn't young and hasn't been artificially tampered with but it's atmosphere is much younger than expected. Earth is on it's second atmosphere, we don't know anything about the first atmosphere (we do have some guesses but no evidence), it was blown off when the moon formed. Your world was recently, geologically speaking, subjected to a series of large comet impacts that blasted most of the old atmosphere off and brought in the fresh volatiles, almost entirely devoid of any noble gases, that compose the current atmosphere.

Thank you, this works really well as my planet has also acquired abiotic oxygen from Titania ( https://www.nature.com/articles/srep13977 ) brought over by comets and meteors

@casualworldbuilder Some, all, of the oceans of this world are likely to be worryingly circular and/or have sharply scalloped shorelines, it's going to take some big hits to strip the old atmosphere away and then a bunch of smaller ones to refresh it. If you're  looking at meteor bombardment bringing in abiotic oxygen you have an excuse for a large trace of Helium-3 (don't have to have it but you can). That is going to vanish relatively quickly due to solar wind action in the Goldilocks Zone but it could be a clue to visitors of just how recently the new atmosphere was laid down.

A young atmosphere would pretty much have to be low in density.  The OP already has issues with a very high density for the gravity; so, I suspect this solution would undermine the other criteria of the setting.

@Nosajimiki We've been steadily losing our atmosphere since the late heavy bombardment and it's still quite thick. Initial post bombardment thickness will also depend on the initial crustal chemistry, you can dump a lot of solid oxides and nitrides while stripping off the original atmosphere and then have a relatively small quantity of cometary debris that reacts with those compounds to form a surprisingly thick atmosphere. Or simply have a lot of small comets pouring down into the atmosphere for a thousand years or so, geologically speaking that's an eye blink.

Your planet took a very long time to accreate
When you look at any of the inner planets, your argon levels are way higher than this because argon is heavier than Oxygen and Nitrogen; so, it is less likely to be blown away by solar winds.  When you look to the outer reaches of the solar system at comets, you will find an Argon/Water ratio of about 100,000:1, which means that comets could get you close to the correct Oxygen/Argon ratio, but may or may not work for your Oxygen/Nitrogen/Carbon ratio. Most elements with the exception of Hydrogen and Noble gases appear to in comets in ratios similar to their cosmic abundances meaning that an average comet contains about 10 parts oxygen, 5 parts carbon and 1 part nitrogen.  So, if you we to bombard a planet with comets, you'd get an atmosphere characterized by high concentrations of Oxygen and CO2 with only a little bit of Nitrogen and Ammonia by comparison.  It will take your planet time to sequester the more chemically active Oxygen and Carbon into soil compounds allowing the relative nitrogen levels to rise, but this time will also lead to your Argon levels rising through a combination of outgassing from the planet and general thinning of the atmosphere simply increasing its relative ratio well above your target goal.
However, there is one place in the solar system that has even less Argon than comets: the asteroid belt.  Because of the range to the sun, the asteroid belt contains significant amounts of solid oxygen and nitrogen containing compounds; however, Argon does not freeze at these temperatures and can not bind with other elements to make compounds that will be solid at this temperature; so, practically all of the Argon has been blown away by solar winds.
In a similar solar system to our own where the first gas giant planet is a bit less massive or farther out than Jupiter, the formation of a rocky planet at the range of the asteroid belt would be possible, but take much longer than the inner planets due to the disturbances caused by the inner Jovian planet.  As such, the Argon could be long gone by the time the planet forms, but the nitrogen and oxygen would still be there to become major atmospheric gases.  You'd probably still start off with a CO2 rich atmosphere, but as this planet ages, it would be possible for it to evolve as Earth did, but with way less starting Argon, you could still have only trace amounts even after most of the early atmosphere's gases have escaped or been sequestered.

Comets can be almost pure ammonia, 82% by weight nitrogen. Otherwise completely reasonable +1.

@Ash I'm sure there have been specific comet ejecta with that much nitrogen, but as a general rule, the composition of comets is about equal to cosmic abundances with the exception of hydrogen and the noble gases which appear in much lower quantities.  enough comet impacts to add an atmosphere to a planet will require many comets, not just one, so it's better to assume the average than the outliers will be true.

Biological activity
Some of your life forms produce cluster argon cations with several argon atoms held together because they have a collective positive charge.  This only works because they are contained by proteinaceous vesicles that maintain the positive charge within a shell of negative charge so distributed so that it cannot transfer to the argon.  The net effect is that the organisms have a large amount of energy stored, which can be released by freeing neutral argon atoms one by one by adding electrons, or converted to propulsion by abruptly reacting the entire vesicle to produce a large amount of gas.  They use these vesicles as a far more potent analogue of oxygen (an electron acceptor) in their metabolism.  The organisms are thus capable of surviving on high, airless peaks of an alien world, and rocketing from place to place through the vacuum.  They also, incidentally, have taken up all the available argon in the planet's atmosphere.
